# Document Not Saving with Mongoose Create() Function Called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code to generate a user profile, and then I am attempting to save this profile to my database using Mongoose's `create()` function. For whatever reason this isn't working. It appears my user profile data is not being passed successfully to the `add()` function in my controller. It's not clear to me why this is the case.

First off, here's my controller's `add()` function:

```
exports.add = async ({
  data = {}
} = {}) => {
  console.log('data: ', data);
  return User.create(data);
};
```

And here's the route info for the above function:

```
router.post('/', async ctx => {
  const data = ctx.request.body;
  console.log('data: ', data);
  const user = await controller.add({
    data
  });
  ctx.body = user;
});
```

And here's the relevant part of the code where I'm calling this function: note I do see the console.log data line running, so I know the function is being called. But for whatever reason `data` is still an empty object (the default), even though I am passed a JSON version of my user doc:

```
  let formattedUser = new User();

  formattedUser = JSON.stringify(userProfile);

  console.log('formattedUser: ', formattedUser); // I see this in my console

  try {
    let createdUser = await UserCtlr.add(formattedUser);
    console.log('createdUser: ', createdUser); // this DOES NOT print to the console
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I'm confused because I can see `formattedUser` being printed to the console BEFORE I pass it to the `add()` function. But the `add()` function only seems to contain an empty object (the default) when that function runs. By the way, I don't get any errors, even though I have this encapsulated in a try/catch.

Another note, I can successfully use Postman to call this `add()` function and save a user to the database. So I'm unclear why it's not working when I call it programatically. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file, you are returning an object created from your User Schema, but not saving that object into the DB.. try returning the following :

```
User.create(data).save();
```

Comment: But if what you're saying is true, how would I be able to successfully save a doc to the database when calling that controller function from Postman? If you look at the docs, `create()` is a Mongoose shortcut that calls `save()` behind the scenes.

Comment: Why would that be helpful? If I can make a successful call from Postman, then the db connection is good. The question is why "data" is being passed to the controller function in the case I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file. Then you created `formattedUser`, you can try:

```
formattedUser.save(function (err, createdUser) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);    
      console.log(createdUser); //If created success
    });
```

Comment: Same result. Does not save to the database.

Comment: Did you try "insert"?

Comment: The issue is why the JSON object saved in "formattedUser" is not getting passed successfully to the controller function. The function logic itself is fine as is. As I mentioned elsewhere, "create" uses "save" behind the scenes.

Comment: you try: console.log(formattedUser) in try{}. i think reason in try{}

Comment: No problem consoling logging that out. Again, the issue is with why the data in "formattedUser" is not being passed successfully to the controller "add()" function. Note that "data" that's being console logged in the controller function shows as being an empty object. So it's not getting there.

Comment: Sr. i don't know. i wish i can help you.